# git how to create local master branch and sync with remote master

Tags: git, macos, github, version-control

I was told this "**Never change the master branch on a fork of a repo, or any branch that came from upstream. Your master branch will diverge from upstream and you won't be able to pull upstream into the local branch.**". This makes sense to me.

I did all my commits into my local master branch. So, taking the above advice I want to keep my master clean now. So, I checked out master to old_master

> **git branch**

```
*master
```

> **git checkout -b patchv1**

Now, all my changes are there in **patchv1** branch.

I force deleted the master branch by running below command

> **git branch -D master**

I thought I'll create orphan master and then git pull

> **git checkout --orphan master**

```
Switched to a new branch 'master'
```

> **git pull**

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master
```

> **git pull remote origin**

```
fatal: 'remote' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

> **git remote show origin**

```
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://giturl/my_org_name/runbooks.git
  Push  URL: https://giturl/my_org_name/runbooks.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    custom-patch-1            tracked
```

Also, when I do git branch it doesn't show this newly created orphan master branch. It just lists my patchv1 branch which I checked out from master before deleting it. And that too, doesn't seem to be my current branch.

> **git branch**

```
patchv1
```

How to recreate the master branch and make sure it's in sync with the remote master?

Answer (score 1):

I think you went the wrong way. An orphan branch is a *new* branch that has *no relationship* whatsoever with the original master branch (be it remote or local). So I assume this is not the way you want to. My best advice would be: `go back to your branch patchv1`. Then the simplest way to sync with *remote* master (after you have checked out `patchv1`) is to simply run:

```
git pull -r origin master
```

That will get the state of the remote branch master, then it will *rebase* your patchv1 branch *on top* of the new position of remote master branch.... and that is, of course, if you want to rebase. If you want to run merges instead, then run the same thing but without the `-r` option.

Now, your local master branch. If you don't intend to use it *at all* then deleting it is fine. Just like you did, I would rather make my local branches set their upstream branch to the remote branches than having to be forced to sync local master first and then pull changes into the feature branches.... but it's a matter of taste, I think.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create an `orphan` of `master`, just `git checkout master` and then `git pull`.

A typical workflow would be to run `git pull` on your local `master` so that it pulls the latest from the `remote` `master` branch. You then create a feature branch off of that: `git checkout -b my-feature`, do your work, and then `git push -u origin my-feature` so that you can open a Pull Request to merge the feature branch into master.

To keep your feature branch up to date with master you can always do `git merge origin/master` (or `git pull -r origin master`, which puts your commits on top of the new commits on `master`).